# Using Agda "rewrite" to prove "composition of maps is map of compositions"

Tags: agda

I'm very new to Agda, and I'm trying to do a simple proof of "composition of maps is the map of compositions".

(An exercise taken from [this course](https://github.com/pigworker/CS410-17))

Relevant definition:

```
_=$=_ : {X Y : Set}{f f' : X -> Y}{x x' : X} ->
        f == f' -> x == x' -> f x == f' x'
refl f =$= refl x = refl (f x)
```

and

```
data Vec (X : Set) : Nat -> Set where
  []   :                              Vec X zero
  _,-_ : {n : Nat} -> X -> Vec X n -> Vec X (suc n)
infixr 4 _,-_
```

I want to prove:

```
vMapCpFact : {X Y Z : Set}{f : Y -> Z}{g : X -> Y}{h : X -> Z} ->
             (heq : (x : X) -> f (g x) == h x) ->
             {n : Nat} (xs : Vec X n) ->
             vMap f (vMap g xs) == vMap h xs
```

I already figured out the proof using `=$=`

```
vMapCpFact heq [] = refl []
vMapCpFact heq (x ,- xs) = refl _,-_ =$= heq x =$= vMapCpFact heq xs
```

But when I tried to do the proof using `rewrite`, I stuck at this step:

```
vMapCpFact heq [] = refl []
vMapCpFact heq (x ,- xs) rewrite heq x | vMapCpFact heq xs = {!!}
```

Agda says the goal is still

> (h x ,- vMap f (vMap g xs)) == (h x ,- vMap h xs)

I wonder why the rewrite of `vMapCpFact heq xs` failed?

Answer (score 5):

Simply because `vMapCpFact heq xs` didn't fire at all. The type of this expression, as reported by Agda, is

```
vMap _f_73 (vMap _g_74 xs) == vMap (λ z → h z) xs
```

i.e. Agda can't infer `f` and `g` (those `_f_73` and `_g_74` are unresolved metavariables) and so it can't realize what exactly to rewrite.

You can fix this by explicitly specifying `f`:

```
vMapCpFact {f = f} heq (x ,- xs) rewrite heq x | vMapCpFact {f = f} heq xs = {!!}
```

Now the type of the goal is

```
(h x ,- vMap h xs) == (h x ,- vMap h xs)
```

as expected.

Or you can rewrite from right to left, since the rhs of the type of `vMapCpFact heq xs` is fully inferred:

```
vMap (λ z → h z) xs
```

For rewriting from right to left you only need to use `sym`. Then the whole thing type checks:

```
vMapCpFact heq (x ,- xs) rewrite heq x | sym (vMapCpFact heq xs) = refl _
```

because the `_f_73` and `_g_74` metavariables are forced to unify with the actual `f` and `g` variables by the `refl`.